# Multi-drop 100Mbps network?

Tags: ethernet, network

We are looking into the possibility to replace our multi-drop SPI (@10MHz) with an alternative solution that allows for more data through put. I've started to look into possibilities of potentially having some 100BASE system customized by possibly usinng PHYs that allow for TD to be set into high impendance mode. Is Multi-drop even doable in the 100MHz range?

Thanks

**edit** 
This would be for maximum of 16 drops (clients) -> fewer might be possible if required. Distance would be across a 9 inch rack, maybe 50cm.... and it would be lines on a PCB

Comment: This question is far too broad to be answered here. You need to give more information about your application, such as how many nodes, distances involved, bandwidth/latency requirements, etc.

Comment: With regard to Ethernet technology in general, only the older coax-based media are truly multi-drop. All UTP-based media (nnn-BASE-T) are strictly point-to-point.

Comment: Since you're already working with SPI, have you considered simply running a dedicated SPI from your master to each slave?

Comment: @Dave Tweed, Yes I'm aware of the fact that only BASE10 existed as a multi drop standard but my question is, is there an option to piggy back ride on 100MHz with multi-drop? see edits above

Comment: running dedicated SPI hasn't been considered but may be an option too. Or currebnt slave MCU can only handle a max of 16MHz on SPI_CLK but we may need to upgrade the CPU too then... it's worth a consideration.

Comment: Do you have a budget constraint ? And technology constraints ? Because using a an ethernet switch IC can be a solution but can be costly as switching IC have a lot a features. You can also consider a FPGA to make an ethernet hub or simple ethernet switch or used as a crosspoint switch.

Comment: @zeqL yes true, we've considered these options but had to abandon due to lack of real estate on PCBs... there's no room for large chips anywhere and we want to keep power consumption low as well.

Comment: Can you add more information in your post regarding the constraints, and maybe a little basic schematics of the intented network ?

Comment: You might be able to do multidrop, but definitely not with stubs. So whatever type of communication you use, you have to route the traces strictly in series, visiting every node one after the other, without junctions. Also, at this speed & distance, you'll have to use strictly matched impedances, which is not impossible on a single PCB, but could prove to be problematic if several connectors are to be crossed (nodes are on different PCBs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LVDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LVDS) as a physical layer will do multidrop into the Gbps.  You might need to roll your own higher comms layers, but iirc Xilinx can supply IP to at least layer 2 go with the LVDS transceivers in their FPGA's.  They also offer GTP transceivers in their higher-end FPGA's but I'm not sure whether GTP supports multidrop.  Also, there are many standalone LVDS SERDES devices, again into the Gbps range, that are designed to do exactly what you want.  Just search for LVDS or SERDES on one of the major electronics vendors websites for examples.